# Can a viewcontroller presented modally over current context (UIModalPresentationStyleOverCurrentContext) be rotated with device?

Tags: ios, uiinterfaceorientation, size-classes, uideviceorientation

I have a controller which should be rotated with interface (device) orientation change. I track orientation changes, however i'm unable to rotate the view with the device orintation changes.

I can animate the views inside, and switch their constraints etc, but i'd like to use Size classes for that. When i switch to UIModalPresentationStyleCurrentContext on presenting the controller it works, but messes with my navigation and tabbar, and i would like to do it this way.

Can it be done this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, solved it.

I track device orientation changes by putting this in viewDidLoad of the controller which needs to change orientation:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                       selector:@selector(orientationChanged:)
                                             name:@"UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification"
                                           object:nil];
```

Then in orientationChanged:

```
- (void)orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)notification{
    [RecorderViewController attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation];
}
```

In order for that to work in the parent controller i added these :

```
-(BOOL) shouldAutorotate {
    return true;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
}
```

Also, for rotation to work recorder controller has to implement these:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return true;
}




- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
}
```

Hopefully somebody finds this useful.