# OverCurrentContext prevents orientation change

Tags: ios, swift, orientation

I'm presenting an `UIViewController` (Lets call it Controller A) over current `UIViewController` (Lets call it Controller B). I want that controller A present on landscape orientation. When I set `overCurrentContext`, It doesn't change the orientation by default (I need to turn left/right the device), however, If I comment `overCurrentContext` code, everything is working.

```
var landscapeOrientation = false
func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    if landscapeOrientation{
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.landscapeRight
    }else{
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait
    }
}
```

How I present the new controller and set orientation.

```
let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
delegate.landscapeOrientation = true

let controller = ToolTipWithCheckImageViewController()
controller.view.backgroundColor = .clear
controller.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext //Which causes the bug
controller.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
topController.present(controller, animated:true)
```

**P.S:** I use this `delegate.landspaceOrientation=true` on some other controllers too and because I'm not presenting it with overCurrentContext, everything is working so there is NOT a problem with that code :)

**P.S2:** Parent controller is an `UINavigationController`

I think this question has some problem with me but I can't figure out the solution provided.
[Can a viewcontroller presented modally over current context (UIModalPresentationStyleOverCurrentContext) be rotated with device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31700372/can-a-viewcontroller-presented-modally-over-current-context-uimodalpresentation)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same effect in a kind of overlay view controller -- if you anyway need a fullscreen "size" at least for the background view you can use .overFullScreen for the modalPresentationStyle instead of .overCurrentContext (which will still show the background via a kind of snapshot, but rotation will still work).